# UIImage View + Pinch/Zoom feature when image is downloaded from web

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a UIImageView, which pics up different images from the web, they are all different res. I have them to display as Aspect fit so that the whole picture displays even if it means leaving empty space on top or sides.

What i want to have the feature of doing is, once its displayed, to zoom in and out using the pinch or any other way.

```
NSURL* iURL = [NSURL URLWithString:tURL];
```

NSData* iData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:iURL];
 UIImage* iImage;
    iImage = [UIImage imageWithData:iData];
 FullScreenImage.image = iImage;

All this code is being executed on another thread, then it returns to the main thread and is displayed on a view using

```
 [navigationController pushViewController:vFullscreen animated:YES];
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a UIScrollView as UIImageView does not offer any built-in zooming. See the Apple example entitled: ScrollViewSuite

Comment: Thanks, When i had a quick look, i needed to know the dimensions of the image, but with images when im downloading, i can not provide this on the fly :/

Comment: Once the image is downloaded, you can get its size from UIImage's size method which you can then use for the scrollview.